# how to implement promiseall on promisify commands with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, redis

I know that to implement promises in redis you have to use a promise. But how would I use those promise functions in a promise.all to work in order. At the moment the promises seem to all be working at the same time.

At the moment here is what my code looks like:

```
const promiseget=promise(client.mget).bind(client);
promiseget(['............']).then(res=>{
.......
........
....


const promiselrange=promise(client.lrange).bind(client);
promiselrange('.......',0,-1).then(res=>{
......
......
.....
})
Promise.all([promiselrange,promiseget]).then((values)=>{
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the truth is that `Promise.all` will wait for all of the promises that are executing concurrently. If you need to have a specific order you need to wait for a promise of a first operation and then perform the next operation e.g.

```
call1()
.then(() => {
   console.log("First operation done!");
   return call2();
})
.then(() => console.log("Second operation done!"));
```

It can look even nicer with `async/await` syntax.